# Latex and file management: chained \include{...} and reference to active directory

Tags: external-files, linux, auxiliary-files, xr, folders

For each chapter of a document I am working on I have a separate folder, and all folders are contained in a common superfolder, together with a file `main.tex` which should put them all together. Ideally, it would be possible to compile each chapter individually, to save some time on compiling and debugging. I am hoping to connect all the files in an efficient and flexible way.

So I did this by using the `standalone`package in the main file, and this works fine. Preferably I would also be able to reference sections/equations/... from other chapters in each of the chapter files, by including their auxiliary files and using the `xr` package for crossreferencing. But I am struggling a bit with the file management.

Here is a minimal `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}

\include{./Chapter1/Chapter1}
\include{./Chapter2/Chapter2}

\end{document}
```

and here is a minimal `Chapter1.tex` file

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{../main}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and similarly for `Chapter2.tex`. However, when I compile `Chapter2.tex` references to Chapter 1 do not work, and I get the warning

```
Package xr Warning:
No file ./Chapter1/Chapter1.aux
LABELS NOT IMPORTED.
```

I presume that this is because when including the main file through `\externaldocument{../main}`, all references to the active directory via `./` are still interpreted with respect to the directory of the file currently being compiled, namely `Chapter2.tex`. What would be the elegant way to get around this, without having to resort to absolute file directories? I work on a Linux system.

Comment: why are you mixing two methods of working on chapters? I would not use standalone here and just use `\include`  to work on just chapter 2 use `\includeonly{Chpater2}` Similarly don't use `xr` and `\externaldocument` when it is all the same docuemnt.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the tip, I was unaware that I was mixing two methods. I understand that your proposal would make only the main document compilable as such, but that I could use \includeonly{} to only make one chapter compiled.

This would make it harder to send e.g. the source files of a specific chapter to a colleague to work on, without them having to either manually add preamble etc., or requiring the main file etc. What would be the other of the two methods I have mixed?

Comment: But that is the only reason for using `\include`. If you are not using `\includeonly` then `\include` introduces many complications and no benefits over `\input` (as all the extra complication is to support `\includeonly`).  If you only want to send a singe file for one chapter without the context from the main file and other chapters then you presumably have to accept that references to other chapters will be broken. If you use standalone and xr then the model is that each document is a separate self standing document so that works (but has some restrictions) but do not use \include then.